# Wrap Function into HTML Table

Tags: php, html, json, html-table

I am new to HTML and PHP. Is there any way I can wrap this in an HTML Table?

[image: This is what the output currently looks like]

[image: This is how I want it to look like]

This is what the code currently looks like:

```html
$measurement = json_decode($orders['measure']);

for($mcounti=0; $mcounti<15; $mcounti++){
    $print_content .= '<div class="">';
    for($mcountj=0; $mcountj<4; $mcountj++){
        $print_content .= '<div class="size' . $mcountj . '">';
        if(isset($measurement[$mcounti])){
            if(trim($measurement[$mcounti][$mcountj]) != ""){
                $print_content .= $measurement[$mcounti][$mcountj];
            }else{
                $print_content .= "-";
            }
        }
        //$print_content .= isset($measurement[$mcounti]) ? $measurement[$mcounti][$mcountj] : '00';
        $print_content .= '</div>';
    }
    $print_content .= '</div>';
}

$print_content .= '</div>';
```

Comment: Well, at its simplest you could just put `<table><tr><td>` before the first `<div>` and `</td></tr></table>` after the last `</div>`.  But that wouldn't really accomplish much.  What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  This is what the output looks like : http://www.passioniorder.de/Output.tiff     and I want this to be in a html table like this  :  http://www.passioniorder.de/Table.tiff

Comment: Show your desired output

Comment: I want the output to look like this  passioniorder.de/Table.tiff  - Hope this is clear otherwise I could also upload something else to make it more clear. Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you are making too many iterations.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Please provide sample JSON (not an image of it), and the desired output for it.